# Namespace in Swift: Differentiate between an enum and a class

Tags: swift, import, namespaces

I'm importing a framework called `Fruits` into my class. Fruits has an Enum `FruitType` which contains `case Banana`. The `Fruits` framework also contains a class `Banana`. Both are public.

```
enum FruitType {
 case Banana
}
```

```
class Banana {
   func eat() -> Bool { ... }

}
```

My current class

```
import Fruits

class ClassA {
      function1() { (banana: Fruits.Banana) in {
          return banana.eat()
        }
      }
      
      func function1<T>(funcparam: (T) -> Bool) {  } 


}
```

The exact details of the function aren't important, but I'm getting an error saying Banana the enum doesn't have the function eat().  How do I differentiate between the enum and the class, while also importing both because I need them both in different places. I need the whole module to be imported too so I can access a lot of other things, so I can't just do

```
import enum Fruits.FruitType
import class Fruits.Banana
```

Though I know this would solve the specific example, I would like to also import the rest of Fruits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can make a file that has a typealias

```
import class Fruits.Banana

typealias BananaClass = Fruits.Banana
```

Then just use `BananaClass` instead in `ClassA`